# LTSPICE time step to small for (0-5V) to (4-20mA) converter

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, 4-20ma

[image]

i am trying to simulate a (0-5v) to (4-20mA) coverter circuit .when i am trying to the transient analysis of the circuit in the Ltspice i getting a time step error i have kept stop time as 100
for both the transistor
20:gate
10:drain
30:source

i can't figure out what the error is?

Comment: Try adding `Rser=0.1` to both your supplies (and maybe also `Cpar=1m`), and ground the non-inverting input of `U3` if you're not using it. If it still complains, add `Rser=10m` to `C2`. If it still won't work, try adding `opt gshunt=1n`, and as a last resort `.opt cshunt=1p`. If these fail, you could try `.opt reltol=10m abstol=1n`, but by then it would mean the models are not that reliable. BTW, there is a `2N7002` in the LTspice database.

Comment: it is not working @aconcernedcitizen,there must be problem in the model ,thanks for help

Comment: I usually try adding 1GIG or 100MEG resistors to ground everywhere. Sometimes that will help identify the problematic node.

Comment: Why is nothing connected to the non-inverting input of the LM2904?

Comment: in image it is not connected but in actual it connected to the source of 2n7002 ,but then to it giving error@ThePhoton